# rightclicking on the remote server, Opera browser, Flash

Tags: logmein

I'm using Logmein as remote control software.
You can use web interface to control another PC without needing to open ports.

But I have a problem.
If I rightclick on the screen it opens the rightclick menu on my local computer (flash configuration) but I'd like to rightclick on the remote computer.
How can I do it?
I guess it's the same problem with other similar software.
I've tried to find some option on Logmein, on the browser (I've tried Firefox, Internet Explorer and Opera) and on flash, withoud success.

cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've contacted Logmein support and they told me that they only support  Internet Explorer and Firefox.

Comment: Indeed - now it's July 2012 and I'm running Chrome on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and there are some weird keyboard interaction issues. Switching to FireFox fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me only on Maxthon 2 and also remote session must be in full screen mode.